# Consume hosted asmx in a secure way

Tags: c#, asmx

I am using the third party payment gateway in my app. The payment gateway providers gave test asmx HTTPS URL for the integration and it has some methods. Using the `HttpWebRequest` I integrated to my app. I am sending `SOAPRequest` and I got the `SOAPReponse`.

How do I ensure data that I am sending is secure? How do I avoid a man in the middle attack?
Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: A MITM i the attacker had a trusted certificate could be done. It would be detected checking the certificate presented by the fake server. To avoid that, attacker should fake also the CA (DNS poisoning). Using DNSSEC + checking the server certificate should be enough

Comment: You should consider making this question in https://security.stackexchange.com/ for better answers

Comment: A suggestion, you could use WCF and let Visual Studio handle all the requests and responses.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the times, one can assume that, if you are making your web-service calls inside a controlled environment where **you can trust**. You can assume that your connection is *safe* **if** you are using [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS). 
However, there are some problems that can come 'hidden' with HTTPS, such as, if someone ['fakes'](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/184068/how-do-i-know-if-a-certificate-authority-is-not-fake) somehow your certification authority inside of your network/machine or has access to your router and is able to change the DNS of your network.

If you want to analyse the traffic inside of your network to understand what is happening behind the scenes, you can use [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/) for that.
If you really wanna go deep and understand all kinds of man in the middle attacks and how to prevent them, I will give some links where you can start with:

[Types of Man-in-the-Middle Attacks](https://www.rapid7.com/fundamentals/man-in-the-middle-attacks/)

[Man in the middle prevention strategies](https://www.computerweekly.com/tip/Man-in-the-middle-attack-prevention-strategies)

But in general: If you are using HTTPS -> *Theoretically* you shouldn't be afraid of a man in the middle attack.

Comment: Consider adding DNSSEC into your answer